# Xamarin App on a Samsung tablet

Tags: android, xamarin

I designed a app for Android using Visual Studio. It runs great on a phone but when I try to run it on a tablet it displays in the corner of the screen (almost quarter of the screen). What can I do to make it display fullscreen on tablet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:rowCount="5"
android:columnCount="3">
<TextView
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_rowWeight=".1"
    android:tag="user"
    android:id="@+id/user"
    android:text="User" />
<TextView
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:tag="test"
    android:layout_rowWeight=".3"
    android:id="@+id/testType"
    android:text="testType" />
<Button
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:tag="button1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />
<Button
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:text="2"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:tag="button2"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />
<Button
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:text="Middle"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:tag="myButton"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />
<TextView
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:id="@+id/testStat"
    android:editable="false"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1" />
<Button
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="3"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:tag="button3"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />
<Button
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:text="4"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:tag="button4"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />
<Button
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight=".3"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:text="Exit"
    android:id="@+id/btnExit"
    android:tag="btnExit"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"         />
    </GridLayout>
```

Comment: You fix your layout to use relative positioning and use the IDE preview to display different sized screens

Comment: Are you writing your app in Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android?

Comment: It would be better if you can share your code with us

Comment: added the code for my main layout. I am using Xamarian.Android.